# Unable to solve error in block and rescue

Tags: python, ansible

i have written a code in ansible with block and rescue method for error handling. i have given when condition in block, so when it satisfies it imports the playbook i have written inside Block.

and for the values in when condition i have given with_items below it.Alignment and everything is good only. but i getting error with that with_items.Below is the tasks part i have written

tasks:

```
  - name: including the user_list
    include_vars: Users.yml
    no_log: 'yes'
  - name: user validating using block
    block:
     - import_playbook: CIname.yml
    when: '"{{ CI_name }}" == item.ci_name and "{{ username }}" == item.username'
    with_items: "{{ user_list }}"
    rescue:
        - name: Update the work notes of the incident when block fails

    always:
      - name: Post the status back to ServiceNow
```

error i am gettin is:

`ERROR! 'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Play be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in Ansible to loop over blocks. I think what you are trying to achieve is a loop on the `import_playbook` module, which should be possible like this:

```
  - name: user validating using block
    block:
     - import_playbook: CIname.yml
       when: CI_name == item.ci_name and username == item.username
       with_items: "{{ user_list }}"
    rescue:
      - ....
    always:
      - ....
```